# Memoize when key does not implement Clone trait

Tags: rust

In the below lazy memoization example, how do I return the memoized value when the key does not implement the `Clone` trait?

In below implementation, as the value of key is already moved, how can we query the value from the store again with the given key?

Is there a better way to write this code when key does not implement the clone trait?

```
struct Cacher<T, Y>
where
    T: Fn(&Y) -> Y,
    Y: Eq + Hash,
{
    store: HashMap<Y, Y>,
    compute: T,
}

impl<T, Y> Cacher<T, Y>
where
    T: Fn(&Y) -> Y,
    Y: Eq + Hash,
{
    fn new(comp: T) -> Self {
        Cacher {
            compute: comp,
            store: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn get(&mut self, key: Y) -> Option<&Y> {
        if self.store.contains_key(&key) {
            self.store.get(&key)
        } else {
            let value = (self.compute)(&key);
            self.store.insert(key, value);
            self.store.get(&key) //<---- This is problematic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "This is problematic" How is that problematic? Doesn't compile? Include the full error. Panics? Ditto. Produces wrong results? Include the expected & actual results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the entry API:

```rust
fn get(&mut self, key: Y) -> &Y {
    if self.store.contains_key(&key) {
        self.store.get(&key).unwrap()
    } else {
        let value = (self.compute)(&key);
        match self.store.entry(key) {
            Entry::Occupied(entry) => unreachable!(),
            Entry::Vacant(entry) => entry.insert(value)
        }
    }
}
```

However, at this point it is better (and more performant) to use the entry API solely:

```rust
fn get(&mut self, key: Y) -> &Y {
    match self.store.entry(key) {
        Entry::Occupied(entry) => entry.into_mut(),
        Entry::Vacant(entry) => {
            let value = (self.compute)(entry.key());
            entry.insert(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Or with combinators:

```rust
fn get(&mut self, key: Y) -> &Y {
    self.store.entry(key).or_insert_with_key(&self.compute)
}
```